# Searching div content through the text entered in a search box

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a functionality where user can search for different brands available with us.
See the image to get what I'm looking for:

[image]
I want to search & replace a div with the brands matching my search.
I'm looking for an idea here, I can easily do that with ajax call but I hope I can do this with simple javascript. Getting load time to as low as possible.
Any ideas whether I can do this with simple javascript?

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Search' class='text'><br>
<input type='checkbox' id='a'>A<br>
    <input type='checkbox' id='b'>B<br>
        <input type='checkbox' id='c'>C<br>
            <input type='checkbox' id='d'>D<br>
```

Simple html here (with no javascript code): http://jsfiddle.net/22nm8o34/

Comment: make a fiddle so that we can just worry about the way out rather writing all these HTML.

Comment: Have added a simple html fiddle. Looking whether searching through this div with javascript on board is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Search' class='text'><br>
<span class="checkbox-wrapper" id="a"><input type='checkbox' id='a'>A<br></span>
<span class="checkbox-wrapper" id="b"><input type='checkbox' id='b'>B<br></span>
<span class="checkbox-wrapper" id="c"><input type='checkbox' id='c'>C<br></span>
<span class="checkbox-wrapper" id="d"><input type='checkbox' id='d'>D<br></span>
```

Wrap each checkbox in a span so that you can hide both the checkbox and value.

Jquery:

```
$('.text').keyup(function submitClosure(ev) {
    $('.checkbox-wrapper').each(function inputElementClosure(index, element) {
        element = $(element);

        if (element.attr('id').indexOf(ev.target.value) > -1) {
            element.show();
        } else {
            element.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Listen to the jQuery keyup event and loop throught each span. If the span id contains some of the input, show it, otherwise hide it.

Hope I understood you question correct? :)

Here is an link the to the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/22nm8o34/8/

Link to lower case solution: http://jsfiddle.net/22nm8o34/10/

And a link to plain javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/22nm8o34/21/

Comment: I dont see jQuery mentioned anywhere in OP, nor in the tag list and the provided fiddle is pure JS. Besides that, your answer is probably great :)

Comment: Solution is really great. Just one thing, this is case-sensitive solution, anyway to make this non case-sensitive?

Comment: I converted my php variable to lower string, so that's okay now. :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, nah but I thought that because he already used jQuery ajax he would be satisfied with a jQuery answer :)

Comment: @JohanSundén - where do OP point out he is using jQuery ajax?

Comment: Oh sorry. Thought that he wrote that in the question. I read wrong! You are really on the offense today my good sir.